# Creating a tween with static vector drawings

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, tween

Not sure what it's really called, but I'm curious as to how I would go about taking two images I've drawn and somehow make Flash tween them. It's hard to explain as I don't know about it other than that I've seen it executed in a few animations before. I know for sure because of some that used it poorly, where the parts of two completely different images transitioned like a tween. I want to try to use this with static images that go together in a short animation. Is this a built-in function in Flash? Or is it some user-made ActionScript function? If either, what's it called or how would I use it?

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand what you mean by tweening 2 images. Can you show us an example of the transitions you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might mean a [shape tween](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WS58E1E1A4-9296-4b75-AB74-D9D545892556.html). But not sure if you wanted to do it in Flash or in code.

Comment: Well shape tweens are done on the timeline, using the Flash IDE. But coding that same effect is another crazy story, and would probably be very complicated.